# How can I convert 128-bit AES encryption key to a string using Python?

Tags: python, aes, codec, aes-gcm

I am trying to decode my 128-bit AES key in byte format to string to store it in the database. I have tried using Python built-in `decode()` with `ascii` and `utf-8` codecs but I get the following errors:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 2: invalid start byte

I am using [cryptography.io](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/aead/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.aead.AESGCM) library for its implementation.

Comment: What format is the key in now? What do you mean by "it is not working"? Always include what it ***is doing*** and what you ***expect it to be doing***.

Comment: @schroeder I have updated the post.

Comment: You can't decode bytes to a string when the bytes don't represent a string. Ideally you'd be storing the bytes in a binary column in the database. Alternatively, encode the bytes to something like base 64 to turn them into an ASCII-safe string.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now you can decompose your problem further: how can you convert a byte to a string? And that is an easy thing to look up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string

Comment: My follow up question is why you want to convert to string in the first place? You can store byte objects in databases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary is often encoded in hexadecimal or base64, in order for it to be handled as text.  Python's `binascii` module can be used to do both types of encoding, as shown below:

```
import random
import binascii

keybinary=random.randrange(0, pow(2,128)).to_bytes(16, byteorder='big')
print('keybinary', keybinary)

keyhex=binascii.b2a_hex(keybinary).decode("utf-8").strip()
print('keyhex', keyhex)

keyb64=binascii.b2a_base64(keybinary).decode("utf-8").strip()
print('keyb64', keyb64)
```

This produces:

```
keybinary b'b3\xfd\xa9\xfe\x11\x86op\x10\x02\x0b\x1bE\x1f\x89'
keyhex 6233fda9fe11866f7010020b1b451f89
keyb64 YjP9qf4Rhm9wEAILG0UfiQ==
```